# Add a custom URL to the Promotion Links >Tiles | SharePoint 2016 On-Prem

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, promoted-links, tiles

We are using **Promoted Links** to point to some other specific urls. The standard `Link Location' [Hyperlink] does not allow URLs like cdb://... because it insists using http:// as a link.

When we delete the Link Location column, it throws on error `TypeError: c is undefined` 
When we untick [required] option for the Link Location and leave it blank, then in the Tiles view when you click on it > it will still try to open the URL from the link location.

How do we overcome this challange?
Do we have to change the default URL point? If so, how?
Or is there an alternative solution?

[image]

Note: we use SharePoint 2016 on-prem.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, we could not replace the default column **Link Location** in Promoted Links app.

In addition, if you want to redirect to a network drive file location,change the Launch Behavior to **New tab** or **Dialog** will make the file address work:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your research :) unless the changing of default LinkLocation is possible via modifing the aspx page? or even add a custom JS script? Never the less, we need to use cdb:// as a link and it won't allow it since it's requesting a http:// address

Comment: Does cdb:// is a file share link?Per my test, file share link is supported.